# Display posts in category (Laravel)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have some tables:

category:

```
id: 1 title: Shirt
id: 2 title: Pant
id: 3 title: Hat
```

product:

```
... (product has some columns and 1 col is category_id)
```

And what I want to display in view is:

```
1. 5 newest posts for all categories
2. 5 newest posts for each category
```

Basically, it'll look like:

```
--* Title :All *--

5 Newest posts
```

--* Title :Shirt *--

5 Newest posts which category_id :1

```
--* Title :Pant*--

5 Newest posts which category_id :2
```

--* Title :Hat *--

5 Newest posts which category_id :3

Any advices, I've searched on google but didn't find the answer :((

Comment: Whats your problem? You can easily achieve this with some query.

Comment: What you've tried?

Comment: Basically, I'm newbie, I don't know how to resolve that :(

Comment: I usually use $product= product::all(); and pass data to view like this: return view('layouts.pages.home',['product' => $product]); ... But this time it's pretty difficult for me

Comment: Check my answer and lets complete it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have two tables, you'd create two models, one for category and one for product. You can do this by running `php artisan make:model Category` and `php artisan make:model Product`

Now you have these models in your App/ folder.

Add the following to your category model in App\Category

```
public function products()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('\App\Product', 'category_id', 'id');
    }
```

Go on to the controller that wants to process these data and add at the top

```
use App\Category;
use App\Product;
```

1. 5 newest posts for all categories

   $product = Product::take(5)->orderBy('id', 'desc')->get();
2. 5 newest posts for each category

   $categories = Category::get();

   foreach ($Categories as $Category) {
       $products[$Category->name] = $Category->products()->take(5)->orderBy('id', 'desc')->get();
   }

Now to pass this on to the view, i like using a "$data" array, the contents of this array can be accessed directly in the views once passed like so

```
$data =  array();
$data['all_products'] = $product;
$data['category_products'] = $products;
```

This can then be passed on as

```
return View('products.detail', $data);
```

where products.detail is your view

You can now loop through these data in your view as
--* Title :All *--

```
@foreach($all_products as $product)
{{$product->name}}
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have category model like this:

```
class Category extends Model
{
    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('\App\Post', 'category_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

You can take 5 Latest post's of every category easily:

```
$Categories = Category::get();

foreach ($Categories as $Category) {
    $Posts = $Category->posts()->take(5)->orderBy('id', 'desc')->get(); // Get 5 Posts
}
```

Comment: But,how can i pass it to the View ?

Comment: Take a look here: `https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/views`, But you can always run php right in view ( which is dirty way )